# How to create a query with ALL keyword instead of IN

Tags: sql-server

```
table: TopProducts [ProductName]
table: Orders [OrderId, ProductName]
table: Products [ProductId, OrderId, ProductName]
```

Would it be possible to get a list of OrderId that have Orders that match all items in TopProducts table. I came up with quick query using IN, however I want to get a list of orders that that a have a entry for each of the entries in TopProducts. Any hints on how to accomplish this?

sample data (TopProducts): ['fish', 'steak', 'chicken']
Would like to get all ProductId's where three separate order exists for each TopProduct
I have tried `select distinct ProductId from Products where name in (select * from TopProducts)`

Comment: Don't repost your closed questions, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67674126/edit) them to bring them on topic.

Comment: I did and then it said it was closed and to edit or open a new one. Since I already did a edit I opened new.

Comment: Your original question still doesn't have any sample data, or expected results. And you can edit a question as many times as you want; not just the once.

Comment: @Larnu please read it more carefully.

Comment: I see no sample data in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674126/one-to-many-query-with-all-instead-of-in); just 3 values. But again, edit your original question to make it on topic...